# How to allow only certain parameters in method in c#

Tags: c#, methods, parameters

is there a way to only allow certain values as parameters in a method. Not at runtime, I mean it already shows an error when coding. For example:

I have this method:

```
public bool addPoints(Guid userId, uint amount)
{
    ...
}
```

It will be called multiple times in the code. But, I only want people to pass certain values. Those values are defined somewhere e.q. a class:

```
public class LeaderboardPoints
{
    public const uint CREATE = 30;
    public const uint REPLICATE = 15;
    public const uint REMIX = 15;
    public const uint COMMENT = 15;
}
```

Is there a way, that I can force the argument to be one of those props? or is there maybe another way to make sure that the right amount is passed?

Thanks!!

Comment: It sounds like you want an [enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/enum)

Comment: ^^^ noting that enums aren't checked - they're just named integers: you *can* pass any value, just: at least it shouldn't happen accidentally!

Comment: *Is there a way, that I can force the argument to be one of those props?* - check the value that's passed and throw an ArgumentException if it's not. Exceptions are problems developers have to resolve, so any developer that uses your code and passes an illegal value will have to modify their code to get it to work. Do give a helpful error message though, such as "Must be one of the const uint values specified in the Leaderboard_Points class" rather than "The value for X is not acceptable" - leaving them wondering "well.. what *would* be acceptable?"

Comment: (I'd combine canton's suggestion too; make it an enum *and* check it if you're bothered. Most developers won't see an enum and then go out of their way to try and pass a value that's not in the enum; they just reach a place where Intellisense says "this argument is a LeaderboardPoints enum" and they pick a value that is sensible, knowing that there ain't much point passing a value that's not in the enum because the receiving code likely won't be programmed to interpret it as anything).. (All in, developers are a subset of humans you're least likely to need to exert significant control over..)

Comment: Side note; do please keep to C# naming conventions (`AddPoints`, `LeaderboardPoints`); this isn't javaScript or PL/SQL

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An `enum` is one option, but enums are just named integers - you *can* get them wrong and pass any integer (it is just more awkward).

Another way to make it *much harder* to pass in something wrong is to encapsulate the values in a type, using a non-public constructor to make it impossible (without reflection at least) to create invalid options. For example:

```cs
public bool AddPoints(Guid userId, Points points)
{
    // something += points.Value
}
//...
public readonly struct Points
{
    public uint Value {get;}
    private Points(uint value) => Value = value;

    public static Points Create {get;} = new Points(30);
    public static Points Replicate {get;} = new Points(15);
    public static Points Remix {get;} = new Points(15);
    public static Points Comment {get;} = new Points(15);
}
// ...
something.AddPoints(userId, Points.Create);
```

You could also optionally give things names, if it helps debugging.

Comment: But every struct has a public parameterless constructor, which means that you can create a variable with Value = 0. Maybe a class is better suited?

Comment: @SomeBody hm; yep, not a bad point

Comment: @Nick you might want to note that ^^^

Answer (score 3):

As others have commented, you can define and use an `enum` type for this:

```
public enum LeaderBoardAction : uint
{
    CREATE = 30,
    REPLICATE = 15,
    REMIX = 15,
    COMMENT = 15
}
```

Then use `Enum.IsDefined()` to ensure no one passes arbitrary values in place of a defined enum label:

```
public bool AddPoints(Guid userId, LeaderBoardAction action)
{
    if(!Enum.IsDefined(typeof(LeaderBoardAction), action))
        throw new ArgumentException("Expected a valid leader board action", nameof(action));

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works of course. But is there a way to prevent even puting something else there? So that you already get an error when coding

Comment: @Nick but seriously, *who would*? Have you ever, in your life, done something like `myString.Contains('a',(StringComparison)123456);` just for a laugh/to see what happens? Or have you just seen VS offer you the list of `StringComparison.Ordinal.., StringComparison.CurrentCulture.., ...` and picked one?

Comment: @Nick Why are you concerned with what a user might do in the future? It's not your responsibility, all you can do is attempt to make it obvious what the _right thing_ is to do, not attempt to prevent every stupid mistake a user might attempt to make.

Answer (score 0):

> or is there maybe another way to make sure that the right amount is passed?

Another approach is to take away the parameter and instead give named methods that they can call; you have just 4 options so it's certainly feasible to:

```
private bool AddPoints(Guid userId, uint amount)
{
    ...
}

public bool AddCreatePoints(Guid userId) => AddPoints(userId, LeaderboardPoints.CREATE);
public bool AddReplicatePoints(Guid userId) => AddPoints(userId, LeaderboardPoints.REPLICATE);
public bool AddRemixPoints(Guid userId) => AddPoints(userId, LeaderboardPoints.REMIX);
public bool AddCommentPoints(Guid userId) => AddPoints(userId, LeaderboardPoints.COMMENT);
```

As with any such things there's always that drag of how much you need to change when adding more options; for my money I would just use an enum and trust developers not to put crazy values in